# Why can we commute the derivative with the integral in $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(ax)}{x²+1}dx$?

Tags: real-analysis

In the textbook Introduction to Nonlinear Dispersive Equations by Linares and Ponce, 2nd ed., page 7, it is said that by taking the derivative with respect to $a$ of the identity

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(ax)}{x²+1}dx = \pi e^{-a}, $$

(which is true for $a>0$), we have

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x\sin(ax)}{x²+1}dx = \pi e^{-a}. $$

My question is why can we commute the derivative with the integral sign? I tried to write

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x²+1}\frac{\cos((a+h)x)-\cos(ax)}{h}dx$$

and to find a function $g(x)$ in $L^1$ that bounds the integrand uniformly in $h$ so i could apply the Dominated Convergence Theorem, but I couldn't. I know we can use residues to compute this integral, but I would like to know why can we commute the derivate with the integral in this case so we get $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x\sin(ax)}{x²+1}dx = \pi e^{-a}$.

Comment: Perhaps see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule .

Comment: Look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Measure_theory_statement

Comment: Don't need the DCT. As a consequence of the last, you just need to find an integrable function $g(x)$ such that $|f_{a}(a,x)|\leq g(x)$ for all $x$  and almost every $a$. In your problem the function $g(x)$ whould be $a/(x^{2}+1)$ which is integrable and since $|\text{sin}(t)|\leq 1$.

Comment: @Yeipi $|x\sin(ax)|$ is not $\le a.$

Comment: @AnneBauval but with this we don't get what I want to prove, which is  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x\sin(ax)}{x²+1}dx = \pi e^{-a}$. I guess I should had been more clear in the question.

Comment: @GEdgar I thought about using the Leibniz integral rule with $a(x)$ and $b(x)$ constants equal to $R$ and then take the limit $R \rightarrow \infty$, but then I don't know how to justify $\lim_{R \rightarrow \infty } \frac{d}{da}\int_{-R}^{R} \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}dx = \frac{d}{da} \lim_{R \rightarrow \infty } \int_{-R}^{R}  \frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}dx$. Do you know why this is true or can I do it in another way?

Comment: Could you not just integrate over the compact domain $[-M,M]$ for $M$ sufficiently large, then get a bound for the remainder using $|\cos(ax)|\leq1$? Then you can just apply the usual rule for differentiation under the integral sign from Riemann integration and show that your approximation tends to the integral over the entire real line as $M\to\infty$.

Comment: @csch2, I tried to that. The remainder is bouded by $1/M$. But I can't see how to bound its derivative wrt to $a$ or show that this derivative tends to zero as $ M\to\infty$. Can you see how to do this?

Comment: @RafaelDeiga sorry - I misread the problem. I see why it is a bit more subtle than that. I'll think about it some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only need to prove that
$$\forall a>0,\qquad\frac d{da}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{-x\sin(ax)}{x^2+1}dx$$
i.e. (integrating the r.h.s. by parts, thereby justifying its convergence)
$$\forall a>0,\qquad\frac d{da}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(ax)}{x^2+1}dx=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{(x^2-1)\cos(ax)}{a(x^2+1)^2}dx.$$
Equivalently (letting $y=ax$), let us prove that for every $\epsilon>0:$
$$\forall a>\epsilon,\qquad\frac d{da}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{a\cos y}{y^2+a^2}dy=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{(y^2-a^2)\cos y}{(y^2+a^2)^2}dy,$$
i.e. that
$$\forall a>\epsilon,\qquad\frac d{da}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(a,y)dy=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}(a,y)dy,$$
where
$$f(a,y):=\frac{a\cos y}{y^2+a^2}.$$
For this, we just apply the usual theorem (derived from the DCT) about differentiation under the integral sign, the main hypothesis being fulfilled:
$$\forall a>\epsilon,\quad\forall y\in\Bbb R,\qquad\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial a}(a,y)\right|\le g(y)$$
where $g\in L^1:$
$$g(y):=\frac1{y^2+\epsilon^2}.$$